# In java, the best way to get the day from a timestamp

Tags: java

Is there a lighter-weight way to round a timestamp to a day in Java than creating a Calendar?

If not, is there a standard way to create a Calendar instance from timestamp without a call to System.currentTimeMillis(), since Calendar.getInstance() involves a call to System.currentTimeMillis()?

Answer (score 7):

To start with: always prefer [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) when working with date and time.

As for the Calendar - you can create one only by calling `getInstance()` (or instantiating `GregorianCalendar`, which is the same usually (but not always)). And you can then set the timestamp with `calendar.setTimeInMillis(..)`

Comment: +1 - This was where I was going to go with my answer.  For whatever bizzarre reason, you can't create an instance of `Calendar` (which possibly rather stupidly contains state) intialized to anything other than the current time...

Comment: technically, you can. If you serialize a calendar with millis=0, to byte array, then you can deserialize the array multiple times to new instance of `Calendar` which will bypass the constructor. But you just don't need to do that.

Comment: +1 but calling getInstance() does not always return a GregorianCalendar!

Comment: @Bozho, as I mentioned in the question, getInstance() calls System.currentTimeMillis() according to the source I was looking at since it initializes the time to be equal to the current time.

Comment: yes, it does, and you can't do anything different. And you shouldn't.